# How to split an unordered linked list into 2 lists according to a key

Tags: java

I have to split a linked list according to a key and using this signature,public void split(UnorderedLinkedListInt list1, UnorderedLinkedListInt list2, int key)

this is my code i have so far:

```
public void split(UnorderedLinkedListInt list1, UnorderedLinkedListInt list2,     int key){
    UnorderedLinkedListInt list3 = this;
    UnorderedLinkedListInt list4 = list3;


    if(key > list3.first.info){
        list1.insertLast(list3.first.info);
        list3.first=list3.first.link;


    }

    if(key <= list4.first.info){
       list2.insertFirst(list4.first.info);
       list4.first=list4.first.link;
      }


  }
```

when i call the method with 1 2 3 4 5 6 it prints 2 3 4 5 6 1 in list1 and nothing in list2, i think i need a loop but everyone i have tried ends up being infinite.
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of algorithm you are asking for is a `partition` if you want to do further reading, and likely you would want to implement it as a loop over the `this` variable.

```
public void split(UnorderedLinkedListInt list1, UnorderedLinkedListInt list2, int key) {

  //Replace this by what ever type is making up your lists nodes
  UnorderedLinkedListInt.Node node = this.first;

  //Check at each step if you have reached the end of the list
  while (node != null) {
    //Partition logic
    if (node.info > key)
      list1.insertFirst(node.info);
    else
      list2.insertFirst(node.info);

    //Update to the next node
    node = node.link;
  }

}
```

Performance Note: If you are using a single-ly linked list it is *always* faster to insert to the front of the list, because inserting anywhere else requires re-iterating through the list.